# what am i doing wrong in Larvavel sanctum logout

Tags: laravel, authentication

I can not delete the tokens and i keep getting the 500 error that "Undefined variable: user".
what i am doing wrong.

my logout function

```
public function logout(Request $request)
    {
        $request->user()->tokens()->delete();
    }
```

[image: nc]

Comment: well there is no variable `$user` there so this doesn't seem like what is throwing the error

Comment: so how do i logout then ? the documentation in laravel is done like what i have done but i get this error

Comment: You can try `$request->user()->currentAccessToken()->delete()` or if user is undefined then `auth()->user()->currentAccessToken()->delete()`.